# How can I create a navbar without an overlapping border?

Tags: html, css

I would like to create a navbar that looks like this: https://www.audacityteam.org/

I tried this but I think this doesn't look right. The border from the notch is on top of the left and right placeholders when it shouldn't be. Also I think I made this too complicated; can this be done with fewer div elements?

```css
:root {
  --background: black;
  --accent: silver;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.placeholder {
  float: left;
  height: 20px;
  width: 30%;
  background: var(--background);
  border-bottom: 3px solid var(--accent);
}

.right {
  float: right;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 25%;
  border-top: 50px solid var(--background);
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  height: 0;
  width: 40%;
}

.container-accent {
  position: absolute;
  left: 24.8%;
  border-top: 53px solid var(--accent);
  border-left: 53px solid transparent;
  border-right: 53px solid transparent;
  height: 0;
  width: 40%;
  transform: scale(1.008, 1.008);
}
```

```html
<div class="placeholder"></div>
<div class="placeholder right"></div>

<div class="container-accent"></div>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: "a better way" Better how? Fewer lines of code? Better browser support? Etc.

Comment: Fewer div containers.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is using pseudo elements `::before` and `::after`. But these are considered "replaced content" and are a little different than real elements when it comes to interactivity.

Comment: Your way is fine. If you inspect the code on the example site you gave us they actually use a different way [they actually use images for the corners]. There is always more than 1 way of doing these things usually. If it works, and isnt messy and not cluttered with unnecessary bits of code, your fine. If your not happy with the look, just keep tweaking the CSS until you are happy. Most larger sites can have 1000's of lines of CSS and HTML so dont sweat it to much.

Comment: "how to create navbar without overlapping borders" - If you dont want the borders, just remove borders from the .container-accent + .placeholder classes No more overlapping issue!